# How to fetch getitem detail in Sitecron execute method

Tags: sxa, sitecron

Would like to fetch item details through getitem() method in Sitecron job execute method. However, We are unable to fetch it.

Sitecron job execute method:

```
 public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            try
            {
              var getDetails= Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID("ID"));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                
            }
        }
```

When we are using `Sitecore.Context.Database`, it is returning `null` instead of database name. We are using Sitecore 9.1.1 with SXA.

Comment: If you are running youe code against the master database and have no access to Context, then you could use `Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master")`

Comment: If you are using Sitecron pass the database name in the Parameters and get it from code like this

`var jobParams = job.Parameters;`
`NameValueCollection parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(jobParams);`
`string databaseName = parameters["database"];`

Comment: @jammykam, We are run this code on CD and CM  server so if we add `Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master")` this code then it will work on master database only and we are not getting any response after adding this code as well in Sitecron job execute method. Is there any permission issue ?

Comment: @Sreekrishnan , we will use this code on CD and CM so we are using `Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem()` so detect database dynamically. And if we provide database name in parameters and it would be for specific database only.

Comment: You do not HAVE a `Sitecore.Context`. That only gets built when Sitecore is serving a page request.